# title attribute triggers mouseleave

Tags: jquery, title

I have the following setup:

```
<div class="outer">
    <a href="#" title="abc" class="inner"></a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YNybz/3/

If you hover main div and pause, after a second it will trigger mouseleave.

(as far as I can tell it happens only in firefox)

I narrowed it down to href tag having a title attribute.

Is there a way to prevent this happening (without removing the attribute)?

First problem is that mouseleave triggers, second that cursor changes for a moment to pointer, and then back to default, this also is not wanted behaviour.

Comment: You mean the native browser "tooltip" that comes from having a title attribute ?

Comment: If that is true, sounds like a bug in Firefox.

Comment: what version of FireFox you tested on? I've tested the demo in FF30 and it works normally, no such a problem.

Comment: @adeneo Yes,  -King King firefox30, win7

Comment: my test in firefox 30 + windows 7: no problem found either

Comment: Can’t reproduce either. Start your FF with all extensions disabled, and see whether the problem persist.

Comment: Same happens to me on `Google Chrome - Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)`